# Add a key to an object at a particular position in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Following is my code, in which based on a certain user type I want to add an additional key to the object at a particular position. Currently I literally duplicating the whole and then passing it to the table. Is there a cleaner way to do the same thing ?

Code -

```
myReportsHeader = () => {
    const { valid_user } = this.props;
    const { tableHeaders } = this.props.tableHeaders
    const { labels: tableLabels } = tableHeaders
    if (valid_user) {
        return {
            tb1: tableLabels.tb1,
            tb2: tableLabels.tb2,
            tb3: tableLabels.tb3,
            tb4: tableLabels.tb4, // Add only if valid_user
            tb5: tableLabels.tb5,
            tb6: tableLabels.tb6,
            tb7: tableLabels.tb7,
            tb8: tableLabels.tb8,
            tb9: tableLabels.tb9,
            tb10: tableLabels.tb10
        }
    }
    return {
        tb1: tableLabels.tb1,
        tb2: tableLabels.tb2,
        tb3: tableLabels.tb3,
        tb5: tableLabels.tb5,
        tb6: tableLabels.tb6,
        tb7: tableLabels.tb7,
        tb8: tableLabels.tb8,
        tb9: tableLabels.tb9,
        tb10: tableLabels.tb10
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee of order of keys of object. You should use arrays for that.

Comment: If you're thinking that properties are in a specific order, then you're probably not doing something right.  While there are some ordering rules, programmatically you should be using arrays for ordered things and properties for indexed things (that don't have an order).  Plus, Javascript does not provide any way to insert a property into a specific order other than at the end of the property list.

Comment: If the data is displayed in a HTML table...just provide a null or something as a placeholder instead. Your pattern will be easier to iterate if converted to an array of arrays.

Comment: @MaheerAli in my data table I am retrieving keys by `Object.keys(myHeaderKey)`  which is giving me keys in a correct order in an array. Let me know if that's also fail in some scenario as for the current implementation I am getting it correctly

Comment: @jfriend00 Let me know if thr is any caveat if I am picking the keys from Object.keys in my data table. Though with the current implementation its giving me correct keys in an array

Comment: There is not particular position in an object, arrays have that.

Comment: @Nesh - You'd have to show us the code that is using the order.  In general, if you want order, then properties are NOT the right tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete keys that must be exclude for invalid user:

```
myReportsHeader = () => {
  const { valid_user } = this.props;
  const { tableHeaders } = this.props.tableHeaders
  const { labels: tableLabels } = tableHeaders
  if (!valid_user) {
    delete tableLabels['tb4']
  }
  return tableLabels
}
```

[Delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Answer (score 0):

You can first construct an object with default values. Then add additional property if the condition is true and finally return it e.g:

```
const obj = {
    tb1: tableLabels.tb1,
    tb2: tableLabels.tb2,
    tb3: tableLabels.tb3,
    tb5: tableLabels.tb5,
    tb6: tableLabels.tb6,
    tb7: tableLabels.tb7,
    tb8: tableLabels.tb8,
    tb9: tableLabels.tb9,
    tb10: tableLabels.tb10
};

if (valid_user) {
    obj.tb4 = tableLabels.tb4, // Add only if valid_user
}

return obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

What [Maheer Ali commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504157/add-a-key-to-an-object-at-a-particular-position-in-javascript#comment99596414_56504157) should be an answer:
Objects don't guarantee the order of their keys.
For that use arrays.

So, you will probably have

```js
const columns = [tableLabels.tb1, tableLabels.tb3];
if (valid) {
  columns.splice(1, 0, tableLabels.tb2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread syntax to avoid duplicate code.

```
 const obj = { ...tableLabels }

if (!valid_user) {
    // Delete tb4 if user is invalid
    delete obj.tb4;
}

return obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this, a combination of [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [destructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
myReportsHeader = () => {
    const { valid_user } = this.props;
    const { tableHeaders } = this.props.tableHeaders;
    const { tb4, ...labels } = tableHeaders.labels;

   return valid_user ? {...labels, tb4 } : {...labels};

}
```